# Facebook Messenger Bot: Understanding Syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I am trying to learn how to create a facebook Bot.

[I found this amazing article on Medium which illustrates how we can create a messenger bot](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-create-your-very-own-facebook-messenger-bot-with-dialogflow-and-node-js-in-just-one-day-f5f2f5792be5)

In this article, The author tells us to create a *verification.js.* file inside *controllers/verification.js.* and paste the following code in it.

```js
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const hubChallenge = req.query[‘hub.challenge’];
  const hubMode = req.query[‘hub.mode’];
  const verifyTokenMatches = (req.query[‘hub.verify_token’] === ‘crowdbotics’);
  if (hubMode && verifyTokenMatches) {
    res.status(200).send(hubChallenge);
  } else {
    res.status(403).end();
  }
};
```

Now, before trying to figure out what this code does (which she have explained), **I am unable to understand why haven't she included any dependencies (precisely express) in this Node.Js file**?

**[Update] Can someone also please explain me in length what does the above code do?**

Since this code looks like NodeJS code, Shouldn't she add something like

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
```

and do `module.exports` after?

Comment: That's about the first line of actual code on that page

Comment: You need to import modules only if you need it. That chunk of code simply exports a function that can be used in any other module by importing it.

Comment: @lucas didn't got you?

Comment: `Once the installation is complete, go to your directory and create a file called index.js and start Express server listening to the port 3000 (you can take any you want).

const express = require(‘express’);
const bodyParser = require(‘body-parser’);
const app = express();`

Comment: @lucas I got that part, my question is what is he trying to do in the above mention code

Comment: @camel_case This may seem a little dumb question to ask? but is he exporting a function without a name? shouldn't it be something like `export FunctionName(){...}`

Comment: @RahulPatel he's just exporting an anonymous es6 arrow function, which is totally legit. It can be imported as `import * as whateverYouNameIt from 'controllers/verification';` or `let func = require('controllers/verification');`. Have a look at [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [node.js module exports](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Comment: @camel_case I swear I though it to be an annyonomous function but wanted to confirm it. Thanks a lot :)
If you could add both your comment in answer section, I will mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: @RahulPatel done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the comments under the question:

1. You must import modules only if you need it. That chunk of code simply exports a function that can be used in any other module by importing it.
2. The author's just exporting an anonymous es6 arrow function, which is totally legit. It can be imported as

   ```
   import * as whateverYouNameIt from 'controllers/verification';
   ```

   or

   ```
   let func = require('controllers/verification');
   ```

   Have a look at [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [node.js module exports](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)